# Как добавить обложку к mp3 файлу?

Tags: java, android, id3v2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно прикреплять к mp3 файлу обложку с помощью java. Может есть какая-нить либа для этого

Comment: Блин, сколько же здесь забаненных на гугле) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510075/adding-cover-art-to-downloaded-mp3-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можешь поискать [здесь](https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla-music-tag-editor)
или есть еще базовая библиотека [mp3agic library](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить примеры использования. А то ответы-ссылки не приветствуются)